# Reassign useForm values on props change

Tags: forms, vue.js, inertiajs

This component is a content of a `Modal` window to update a user, every time it shows, the component recieves user to edit as `user` prop, when it opens, i want to show the user old values as the input default values so i stored the values of `user` prop in the `useForm`, but the problem with this is that it will only works the first time, if modal shows for a second time and different user, it will still show the old data of the previous user because it is already stored in `useForm` values and it will not reassign these values if `user` prop changed, how can i make it listen to `user` prop change? thanks in advance.

`UpdateUser.vue`

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { FilterMatchMode } from "primevue/api";
import { Head, router } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import CreateUser from "./Forms/CreateUser.vue";
import { useToast } from "primevue/usetoast";
import Modal from "@/Components/Modal.vue";
import UpdateUser from "./Forms/UpdateUser.vue";
const toast = useToast();

const props = defineProps({
    users: Object,
});

const users = ref(props.users);
const userToDelete = ref();
const userToUpdate = ref();
const dt = ref();
const deleteUserDialog = ref(false);
const createUserDialog = ref(false);
const updateUserDialog = ref(false);

const deleteUsers = ref(false);
const selectedUsers = ref([]);
const filters = ref({
    global: { value: null, matchMode: FilterMatchMode.CONTAINS },
});

const confirmDeleteUser = (prod) => {
    userToDelete.value = prod;
    deleteUserDialog.value = true;
};
const deleteUser = () => {
    router.delete(route("users.destroy", userToDelete.value.id));
    deleteUserDialog.value = false;
    userToDelete.value = {};
    toast.add({
        severity: "success",
        summary: "Successful",
        detail: "User Deleted",
        life: 3000,
    });
};

const updateUser = (prod) => {
    userToUpdate.value = prod;
    updateUserDialog.value = true;
};

const exportCSV = () => {
    dt.value.exportCSV();
};
const confirmDeleteSelected = () => {
    deleteUsers.value = true;
};
const deleteSelectedUsers = () => {
    const ids = [];
    selectedUsers.value.forEach((val) => {
        ids.push(val.id);
    });
    router.delete(route("users.destroy", ids));
    deleteUsers.value = false;
    selectedUsers.value = null;
    toast.add({
        severity: "success",
        summary: "Successful",
        detail: "Users Deleted",
        life: 3000,
    });
};
</script>

<template>
    <Head title="Students" />

    <div class="row content usersTable">
        <div class="card">
            <Toolbar class="mb-4">
                <template #start>
                    <Button
                        label="New"
                        icon="pi pi-plus"
                        severity="success"
                        class="mr-2 rounded"
                        @click="createUserDialog = true"
                    />
                    <Button
                        label="Delete"
                        icon="pi pi-trash"
                        severity="danger"
                        class="rounded"
                        @click="confirmDeleteSelected"
                        :disabled="!selectedUsers || !selectedUsers.length"
                    />
                </template>

                <template #end>
                    <FileUpload
                        mode="basic"
                        accept="image/*"
                        :maxFileSize="1000000"
                        label="Import"
                        chooseLabel="Import"
                        class="mr-2 inline-block"
                    />
                    <Button
                        label="Export"
                        icon="pi pi-upload"
                        severity="help"
                        class="rounded"
                        @click="exportCSV($event)"
                    />
                </template>
            </Toolbar>

            <DataTable
                ref="dt"
                :value="users"
                v-model:selection="selectedUsers"
                dataKey="id"
                :paginator="true"
                :rows="10"
                :filters="filters"
                paginatorTemplate="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink CurrentPageReport RowsPerPageDropdown"
                :rowsPerPageOptions="[5, 10, 25]"
                currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} users"
            >
                <template #header>
                    <div
                        class="flex flex-wrap gap-2 align-items-center justify-content-between"
                    >
                        <h4 class="m-0">Manage Users</h4>
                        <span class="p-input-icon-left">
                            <i class="pi pi-search" />
                            <InputText
                                v-model="filters['global'].value"
                                placeholder="Search..."
                            />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </template>

                <Column
                    selectionMode="multiple"
                    style="width: 3rem"
                    :exportable="false"
                ></Column>
                <Column
                    field="studentNumber"
                    header="Student number"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                ></Column>
                <Column
                    field="email"
                    header="Email"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                ></Column>

                <Column
                    field="fullName"
                    header="Full name"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="fatherName"
                    header="Father name"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                ></Column>
                <Column
                    field="motherName"
                    header="Mother name"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="fatherName"
                    header="Father name"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="placeOfBirth"
                    header="Place of birth"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="dateOfBirth"
                    header="Date of birth"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="phoneNumber"
                    header="Phone number"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="address"
                    header="Address"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="fatherPhone"
                    header="Father phone"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="motherPhone"
                    header="Mother phone"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="studentExtraJob"
                    header="Student extra job"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="fatherProfession"
                    header="Father's profession"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 13rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="motherProfession"
                    header="Mother's profession"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 14rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="fatherPlaceOfBirth"
                    header="Father place of birth"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 14rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="motherPlaceOfBirth"
                    header="Mother place of birth"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 14rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="nationality"
                    header="Nationality"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="city"
                    header="City"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="nationalId"
                    header="National ID"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column
                    field="gender"
                    header="Gender"
                    sortable
                    style="min-width: 12rem"
                >
                </Column>
                <Column :exportable="false" style="min-width: 8rem">
                    <template #body="slotProps">
                        <Button
                            icon="pi pi-pencil"
                            class="mr-2 mb-2 rounded-circle"
                            @click="updateUser(slotProps.data)"
                        />
                        <Button
                            icon="pi pi-trash"
                            severity="danger"
                            class="rounded-circle"
                            @click="confirmDeleteUser(slotProps.data)"
                        />
                    </template>
                </Column>
                <Toast />
            </DataTable>
        </div>

        <Dialog
            v-model:visible="deleteUserDialog"
            :style="{ width: '450px' }"
            header="Confirm"
            :modal="true"
        >
            <div class="confirmation-content">
                <i
                    class="pi pi-exclamation-triangle mr-3"
                    style="font-size: 2rem"
                />
                <span v-if="userToDelete"
                    >Are you sure you want to delete
                    <b>{{ userToDelete.fullName }}</b
                    >?</span
                >
            </div>
            <template #footer>
                <Button
                    label="No"
                    icon="pi pi-times"
                    text
                    @click="deleteUserDialog = false"
                />
                <Button
                    label="Yes"
                    icon="pi pi-check"
                    text
                    @click="deleteUser"
                />
            </template>
        </Dialog>
        <Modal :show="createUserDialog" @close="createUserDialog = false">
            <CreateUser @close="createUserDialog = false" />
        </Modal>
        <Modal :show="updateUserDialog" @close="updateUserDialog = false">
            <UpdateUser
                @close="updateUserDialog = false"
                :user="userToUpdate"
            />
        </Modal>

        <Dialog
            v-model:visible="deleteUsers"
            :style="{ width: '450px' }"
            header="Confirm"
            :modal="true"
        >
            <div class="confirmation-content">
                <i
                    class="pi pi-exclamation-triangle mr-3"
                    style="font-size: 2rem"
                />
                <span v-if="users"
                    >Are you sure you want to delete the selected users?</span
                >
            </div>
            <template #footer>
                <Button
                    label="No"
                    icon="pi pi-times"
                    text
                    @click="deleteUsers = false"
                />
                <Button
                    label="Yes"
                    icon="pi pi-check"
                    text
                    @click="deleteSelectedUsers"
                />
            </template>
        </Dialog>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that issue by using `onMounted` hook to reset form values :

```
import { onMounted } from "vue";

onMounted(() => {
    form.reset();
});
```